# How to add open box around the X axis label

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotations

I am drawing a picture of go annotation result using ggplot2, i want to add three open boxes underneath the X axis label to identify the main classes of go annotation. Is there anyone can help me?  The picture just look like that as below.

[image]